# Почему кнопку 'в корзину' на мобильной версии нужно кликнуть два раза? Как исправить?

Tags: css

Пожалуйста подскажите как исправить данный баг! Нужно, чтобы одного клика было достаточно!

```
.vitrButton{
  margin-top:20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
height:30px;
background: rgb(47, 120, 188);
color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #4072A1;
font-size:16px;
font-weight: 700 ;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #cccccc;
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
transition: 0.3s;
        }
 .vitrButton:hover{
 background: rgba(42, 107, 167, 1);
          }

    .vitrButton:focus {
outline: none;
            }
```

Comment: Ты хотя бы обработчик свой покажи. Что гадать то всем как он выглядит

Comment: @MegaRoks сорри, забыл!)  Добавил

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transition из-за этого кажется что долго и ты кликаешь два раза

Comment: @MegaRoks  убрал и transition и hover , в итоге всё также

Comment: @Эрик `display: none;` - зачем это? Где это меняется? Должен ведь быть обработчик клика по кнопке.